# Samsung Knox - Keyboard Problem

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, gboard, samsung-knox

I was wondering if anyone would be of any assistance to me.
I have a Samsung Galaxy S4  (Google Edition) smartphone.

I have recently setup KNOX for business use, and safely connecting to servers etc.
However, my keyboard does not work at all in the KNOX application, but it works fine in Personal Home?

Does anyone have any ideas of what this may be?
I am using Google Keyboard, since I do not really like the stock Samsung Keyboard.

Thanks in advance,

Ben

Answer (score 1):

Swiftkey is free and works inside and outside Knox

Answer (score 0):

I just set up a Knox container myself and it seems that it is a secure sandbox environment that does not have access to your regular apps (any downloaded keyboard included) or even the Play store at all. It has its own Knox store, I suppose to keep the Knox container more secure. I was able to find a keyboard app for sale (Quickwrite Keyboard) in the Knox store but it's not cheap.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you changed Keyboard default. You have to setup "Samsung keyboard" as default when using KNOX